# How to remove text before {{expression}} in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having troubles with a simple idea. How do I remove the "Hello" when the user clicks the input field to only show the text that they are typing.

I need the "Hello" in the H1 tag to stay and only disappear when the user clicks the input field to start typing.

```
<div>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">

  <h1>Hello {{yourName}}</h1>
</div>
```

I have tried using jquery to empty or detach the H1 tag but that takes away the expression also.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it within the binding syntax:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">

  <h1>{{yourName || 'Hello'}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this is best answer to the question.

Comment: Perfect! Essentially the || makes the value null so Hello doesn't appear anymore?

Comment: @BradleySmith no. empty string is falsy, so the `||` behaves like javascript's `||` and returns the right handside.

Answer (score 1):

you can keep the hello text into one span and give it a class.

```
<span ng-if="yourName">hell0</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another variable

```
<h1>{{ myLabel }}{{yourName}}</h1>
```

and then in controller

```
$scope.myLabel = 'Text as you please'; //'' to clear
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your `Hello` inside a `span` as:

```
<div ng-app>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">

  <h1><span id="temp">Hello </span>{{yourName}}</h1>
</div>
```

Now you can write this jquery to make your functionality work:

```
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $("#temp").hide();
    })

    $("input").blur(function(){
        $("#temp").show();
    })
```

Link attached now:http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/jrLBRA

Hope this helps!!

Comment: this is not an angular way.

Comment: @Aakash - Yes ofcourse your code works, There are numbers ways to acheive the goal. but we take only the smartest way like Daniel answered.

Comment: Angular way was not asked. Had it been asked that way, my solution would have been different. Hope it helps somebody. @ni3aj

Comment: Agree. Cheers!! @SudharsanS

Comment: I don't think that Daniel's functionality is implementing the solution properly. I mean the requirement was `I need the Hello in the H1 tag to stay and only disappear when the user clicks the input field to start typing.` In Daniel's solution, on clicking the input box `Hello` still stays. Once you start typing, then it goes away.Correct me if I am wrong @SudharsanS

Comment: Daniel answer accepts by the OP. It sounds like daniel post the right answer as per the question. If you still any clarification just ask the OP.

Comment: Yup Someone downvote it . It sounds like your answer is not correct.

Comment: edited the answer. Only thing I did now was added my codepen link. I don't know how the downvoters felt the answer to be wrong.@SudharsanS